# Function to make a deep copy of a LinkedList C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a function to make a deep copy of a linkedlist:

```
void LinkedList::copyData(Node* sourcePtr, Node*& headPtr, Node*& tailPtr)
{

    int currentData = 0;

    if (sourcePtr == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    headPtr = NULL;
    tailPtr = NULL;

    headPtr = new Node(sourcePtr->getData(), headPtr);

    tailPtr = headPtr;

    sourcePtr = sourcePtr->getNextPtr();

    while (sourcePtr != NULL)
    {
        currentData = sourcePtr->getData();

        insert(tailPtr, currentData);

        sourcePtr = sourcePtr->getNextPtr();
    }
} //end function
```

where sourcePtr is the head pointer of a list to be copied, and headPtr and tailPtr are the pointers of a list that are going to be replaced with the list from sourcePtr.

I need to use the & for the head and tail as the linkedlist is being replace and all data must be removed.

In the program I call:

```
list1.copyData(list2.getHeadPointer(), list1.getHeadPointer(), list1.getTailPointer());
```

Where list1 and list2 are arrays of int array1[3] = {1, 2, 3} and array2[3] = {4, 5, 6}.

The above does not work as the functions do not match.

getHeadPointer() and getTailPointer() both return the address of a pointer.

```
Node* LinkedList::getHeadPointer()
{
    return headPtr;
}
```

but to satisfy the function should I be adding &'s inside, how would I do this?

```
list1.copyData(list2.getHeadPointer(), list1.getHeadPointer()&, list1.getTailPointer()&);
```

Currently the classes are node class -> linkedlist class -> random class -> program

random class will be using instances of linkedlist so i need to be able to call the copyData function without randomclass knowing about nodes.

I hope that makes some sense of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Is this part of a homework exercise? The standard C++ template library already has nice containers which act like linked lists (`std::list`).

Comment: Its an example from a text book, I am just having major problems recreating it...

Comment: I have a question, if `list1` and `list2` are **arrays** as you said, how exactly are you trying to call `list2.getHeadPointer()`?!

Comment: And there is a bug in your program. You take a non-empty list (`list1`) and just change its `head` and `tail` to `NULL`! This way all the memory that used to be in that list are lost and you create garbage. What you should do is to `free` the list being overwritten first (above the lines that say: `headPtr = NULL; tailPtr = NULL;`)

Answer (score 1):

The function

```
void LinkedList::copyData(Node* sourcePtr, Node*& headPtr, Node*& tailPtr)
```

appears to be a `static` member of `LinkedList`.

However the designed seems be botched, so one can't be sure (and you don't say anything more about this).

Assuming that it's a `static` member then it can probably be called like this:

```
void foo( Node* source )
{
    Node*    newHead;
    Node*    newTail;

    LinkedList::copyData( source, newHead, newTail );
    // Now use the pointers to the copy.
}
```

Since it's botched there is, however, also a good chance that the above call will *NOT* work. For example, that the destination list must be created first. Only you, the OP, can know that, because only you have the code and specification of this thing.

It is, essentially, backwards to ask others how to call the function.

You're the only one in a position to know; we can only *guess*, very roughly.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you misunderstand the pass by reference semantics. Assign those pointers to variables of type `Node*` first before passing them to the function, and pass them naturally (i.e. without any additional symbols):

```
Node *hp2 = list2.getHeadPointer();
Node *hp1 = list1.getHeadPointer();
Node *tp1 = list1.getTailPointer();
list1.copyData(hp2,hp1,tp1);
```

Comment: The problem is the program cannot see the node class, i could use include obviously but I and trying to get it to just rely on the class below it. so there is node class, linkedlist class which contains instances of nodes. The program has instances of linkedlist and cannot see node.

Comment: well, that's kinda weird. if you're expecting copyData method to be called from outside of its context and you know it depends on another class as parameter, surely both must be included by module that would call copyData. don't overengineer your program, that won't make your modules loosely coupled anyway. having program to include both is the correct solution.

Comment: @Cheeseman If you just need pointers to `Node` and you don't want to include `Node` in the other class, just write `class Node;` above where you define the other class and you can use `Node *` as much as you want. You should note that however in this case `Node` is an _incomplete type_ and no variable of type `Node` itself could be used, or `sizeof(Node)` for example and such!